# What is my cs:go rank?

Tags: counter-strike-global-offensive

First time playing Counter-Strike: Global Offensive today. I've played two competition matches: first one was a tie 15 round each, second game we won 15-4.

I cannot find anywhere what my current rank is. Am i over looking it or is there something I'm not doing?

Answer (score 16):

You must **WIN** 10 matches before your rank is calculated.  So playing 2 matches won't allow you to find it anyway.

[Here](http://steamcommunity.com/sharedfiles/filedetails/?id=312582297) is more information on how the ranking system works, what you need to get ranked, what you need to level up, etc.

> Every new account will display its skill group after 10 Wins (NOT 10 games) and every expired rank due to inactivity will be displayed after a Win (again, not a game). The Skill Group displayed is based on Elo Points, not the other way around. This is the most important thing to remember.

Comment: This should be the answer.... Why not accept it...